# How can I use a NETLINK socket to data from kernel space in PYTHON?

Tags: python, linux, netlink

How can I use a NETLINK socket to data from kernel space in PYTHON?

Comment: There are netlink libraries. You might need to be more specific in your question. You ought to go through your previous questions and accept some answers too.

Answer (score 4):

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_RAW)
sock.bind((0,0))
sock.send(<nlmsghdr>)
sock.recv()
```

Comment: Do you maybe know an answer to the question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876323/netlink-multicast-in-kernels-above-4)?

Comment: Use sock.bind((0,-1)).  The second argument (-1) is a bitmask of groups to monitor. Setting to -1 sets all bits in the mask.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the `socket` Python module has had support for `AF_NETLINK` sockets since Python 2.5 or so, although I have never used it. There are a few projects out there that use it and can serve as an example:

- [pynl80211](http://git.sipsolutions.net/?p=pynl80211.git;a=tree)
- [iotop](http://repo.or.cz/w/iotop.git/tree)

Searching Google for `/usr/bin/python af_netlink` comes up with a few more hits, although I will admit that most are not really useful.