# Python Netlink Multicast Communication in Kernels above 4

Tags: python, c, linux-kernel, multicast, netlink

I was trying to reproduce the example from a previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691305/multicast-from-kernel-to-user-space-via-netlink-in-c) on a kernel above 4 (4.1):

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <net/netlink.h>
#include <net/net_namespace.h>

/* Protocol family, consistent in both kernel prog and user prog. */
#define MYPROTO NETLINK_USERSOCK
/* Multicast group, consistent in both kernel prog and user prog. */
#define MYGRP 31

static struct sock *nl_sk = NULL;

static void send_to_user(void)
{
    struct sk_buff *skb;
    struct nlmsghdr *nlh;
    char *msg = "Hello from kernel";
    int msg_size = strlen(msg) + 1;
    int res;

    pr_info("Creating skb.\n");
    skb = nlmsg_new(NLMSG_ALIGN(msg_size + 1), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!skb) {
        pr_err("Allocation failure.\n");
        return;
    }

    nlh = nlmsg_put(skb, 0, 1, NLMSG_DONE, msg_size + 1, 0);
    strcpy(nlmsg_data(nlh), msg);

    pr_info("Sending skb.\n");
    res = nlmsg_multicast(nl_sk, skb, 0, MYGRP, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (res < 0)
        pr_info("nlmsg_multicast() error: %d\n", res);
    else
        pr_info("Success.\n");
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Inserting hello module.\n");

    nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, MYPROTO, NULL);
    if (!nl_sk) {
        pr_err("Error creating socket.\n");
        return -10;
    }

    send_to_user();

    netlink_kernel_release(nl_sk);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("Exiting hello module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

However, compilation works fine, but when I insert the module, it returns:

```
nlmsg_multicast() error: -3
```

I dont even know, where I can lookup the error codes to learn, what -3 means in this context (I searched [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netlink.h), but was unable to find anything useful, regarding the error code).

Just to be sure, I post the userland code (Python) also:

**EDITED due to a comment:** (but still not working)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import os
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.NETLINK_USERSOCK)

# 270 is SOL_NETLINK and 1 is NETLINK_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
sock.setsockopt(270, 1, 31)

while 1:
  try:
    print sock.recvfrom(1024)
  except socket.error, e:
    print 'Exception'
```

Comment: Most kernel functions in case of error return value `-<error-code>`, where *<error code>* is commonly known in user space as `errno` (`EINVAL`, `ENOMEM` and so on). In the kernel error codes are defined in [include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L25). That is, return value `-3` corresponds to `ESRCH` error.

Comment: That was a thing I didn't know, thanks for that! Do you also know, why this happens in the context of my two programs?

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307767/3440745) to the question you refer to **explicitely says**, that simple `bind()` in user-space is insufficient for binding with given multicast ID. You need to register membership in this group using `setsockopt`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again and sorry for not responding instantly, I had to test a few things. However, I tried setsockopt, as follows: sock.setsockopt(270, 1, 31). 270 is SOL_NETLINK and 1 is NETLINK_ADD_MEMBERSHIP. It simply doesn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to bind the socket. :-)

I'm not very fluent with Python, so use this only as a starting point (between the `socket` and the `setsockopt`):

```
sock.bind((0, 0))
```

That prints me a bunch of garbage, among which I can see

```
Hello from kernel
```

---

By the way: When `nlmsg_multicast()` throws `ESRCH`, it's usually (or maybe always) because there were no clients listening.

First open the client, **then** try to send the message from the kernel.

Otherwise you can always ignore that error code it that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This is not _exactly_ the answer I was looking for (had a lot of tries with bind() also ;-) ). But you helped me sooooo much. The error was, that I had the bind() call **after** the setsockopt(). Now it works. I would give you 100 upvotes if I could ;-)

Comment: @user1252280 can you please tell me how "printing of a bunch of garbage" characters problem can be solved, because when I print I also get the output like "\x00\x00\x00\Hello from kernel\x00\x00\x00\". I tried  decode("utf-8") but it also didn't work. Thanks